# Different result using grep

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I have two files below:

```
$cat file1
"2020051576BPI";"TS.1.BPI.20121129120000.005.txt";"Error";"'OF_USM_DBTI0000029'/'CO_SERVICE_SVCID11066'/'CO_FA_SC_600224'/. appears less times in the Input File (0), but should appear at least 1 times";""
"2019707951BPI";"TS.1.BPI.20121129120000.014.txt";"Error";"'OF_USM_DBTI0000029'/'CO_SERVICE_SVCID11066'/'CO_FA_SC_600224'/. appears less times in the Input File (0), but should appear at least 1 times";""
"Failed to parse string. Error msg: Failed to parse 'Fatal Error at file (buffer) "", line 366, column 17   Message: Expected whitespace'"
```

```
$cat file2
"'OF_USM_DBTI0000029'/'CO_SERVICE_SVCID11066'/'CO_FA_SC_600224'/. appears less times in the Input File (0), but should appear at least 1 times"
"Failed to parse string. Error msg: Failed to parse 'Fatal Error at file (buffer) "", line 366, column 17   Message: Expected whitespace'"
```

I am reading file2 and using grep i am finding line in file1(large file). I am doing it as below:

```
$cat file2|while read line
do
grep $line file1
done
```

But i am getting below result as below:

```
grep: can't open appears
grep: can't open less
grep: can't open times
grep: can't open in
grep: can't open the
grep: can't open Input
grep: can't open File
grep: can't open (0),
grep: can't open but
grep: can't open should
grep: can't open appear
grep: can't open at
grep: can't open least
grep: can't open 1
grep: can't open times"
USM_GRPSET_BPI_ERROR_20121130_171648.TXT:"2020051576BPI";"TS.1.BPI.20121129120000.005.txt";"Error";"'OF_USM_DBTI0000029'/'CO_SERVICE_SVCID11066'/'CO_FA_SC_600224'/. appears less times in the Input File (0), but should appear at least 1 times";""
USM_GRPSET_BPI_ERROR_20121130_171648.TXT:"2019707951BPI";"TS.1.BPI.20121129120000.014.txt";"Error";"'OF_USM_DBTI0000029'/'CO_SERVICE_SVCID11066'/'CO_FA_SC_600224'/. appears less times in the Input File (0), but should appear at least 1 times";""
grep: can't open to
grep: can't open parse
grep: can't open string.
grep: can't open Error
grep: can't open msg:
grep: can't open Failed
grep: can't open to
grep: can't open parse
grep: can't open 'Fatal
grep: can't open Error
grep: can't open at
grep: can't open file
grep: can't open (buffer)
grep: can't open "",
grep: can't open line
grep: can't open 366,
grep: can't open column
grep: can't open 17
grep: can't open Message:
grep: can't open Expected
grep: can't open whitespace'"
USM_GRPSET_BPI_ERROR_20121130_171648.TXT:"2019714006BPI";"TS.1.BPI.20121129120000.005.txt";"Error";"Failed to parse string. Error msg: Failed to parse 'Fatal Error at file (buffer) "", line 366, column 17   Message: Expected whitespace'";""
```

Answer (score 4):

Try quoting what you are looking for:

```
while read line
do
  grep -F "$line" file1
done < file2
```

Comment: +1. Quote all the things! You should also do `grep -F -e "$line"` since you're looking for exact strings rather than a regular expression (and just in case a line starts with a `-`).

Also, the `cat` isn't necessary; you can just put `<file2` on the line with the `done`.

Comment: I tried above but it showed error:grep: illegal option -- f
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- f
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: @sandeep7289, try a capital "F", not a lower case one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the pattern.

But, I suspect what you actually should be doing is supply the strings of `file2` directly to grep thorough the `-f` switch:

```
grep -Ff file2 file1
```

Then any fixed string in `file2` will be grepped from `file1`.

Note, if the lines of `file2` are regular expressions you should omit the `-F` switch.

Comment: I tried above but it showed error:grep: illegal option -- f Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . . grep: illegal option -- f Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: @sandeep7289: What version of grep is this? Both `-F` and `-f` should be supported by [POSIX 1003.1-2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) compliant versions of grep.

Answer (score 0):

Add double quotes to the first parameter of grep

```
grep "$line" file1
```

OR

```
grep "${line}" file1
```

Comment: That's actually the *first* parameter, but that doesn't affect the use of quotes, which you should always use around any parameter expansion unless you intend for it to be treated as multiple shell words.

Comment: Yes. Sorry ... I will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes and drop the [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat):

```
while read line
do
  grep -F "$line" file1
done < file2
```

Comment: I tried above but it showed error:grep: illegal option -- f Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . . grep: illegal option -- f Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: `-F` means uses fixed strings instead `regexp` Isn't necessary though, so if your implementation of `grep` doesn't have that option then just ignore it. Do `grep --help` to see if you have an option to use fixed strings if you're interested.